# What makes delegate multi target object to stay in scope?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, garbage-collection

What makes `t` a rooted reference (stay in scope) ? (`t` is a user defined class)

I look at in in IL spy, and its not a common capture variable !

```
Action runs = null;
while (dummy <= tod.Value.Date)
{
   var t = new Task(dummy, _interval);
   runs += t.Run;

   dummy = dummy.AddDays(1);
}
GC.Collect();
((Action)(() => { runs(); })).BeginInvoke(Result, null);
```

Can someone explain this to me? How the `t` (task) classes stay in scope,  what makes it rooted, I guess its the runs delegate, but how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, I should point out that this doesn't have much to with *scope*, which is the region of program text in which one can refer to an entity using its simple name. It's about *reachability*.

<s>Now I haven't looked at the heap in question with a memory profiler</s>, but the path to a `Task` object would look something like this:

1. The  `Action` (multicast) delegate instance is a GC root since it is referenced by `runs` (a local).
2. This delegate instance in turn keeps its  individual subscribers alive through its `_invocationlist` field, which holds a reference to a delegate array.
3. This array in turn contains references to the individual (unicast) `Action` delegate instances.
4. Each of these individual delegates will be a *closed-instance* delegate with a populated `_target` field (which will act as the `this` reference passed to the `Task.Run` method when the delegate is invoked). This field will hold a reference to the `Task` instance.

To summarize:

```
    runs local
-> Multicast Action object
-> (through _invocationlist field) Array of references to Action objects
-> (through a specific array element) Unicast Action object
-> (through _target field) Task object
```

---

**UPDATE:**

I ran this through [Ants Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/), which confirmed my thoughts:

[image: Path to Task object]